# Ability to select a pre-commit record for edits in a flow once generated

Tags: visual-workflow, plugin

I am in the process of building a flow whereby a guest user creates several records that are stored in a collection variable iteratively until the user indicates that they are done creating these records, at which point the collection records are created. The user can keep adding to the collection variable, but I was wondering if there are any solutions to the ability to access one specific record in the collection variable to edit. For example:

Guest creates item A with fields Name, Age, Weight

Guest indicates they would like to create another item

Guest creates item B with fields Name, Age, Weight

Guest returns to summary screen, where they see that item A's Age was entered incorrectly. Guest selects item A to edit and proceeds.

Guest edits item A, returns to summary screen, confirms the summary, the records are created.

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any specific issues you're facing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.